Has pushed vs. has been pushed
Bob pushes John, and he hits his head on the door. Peter comes up to John to help him. Suddenly, Peter's phone rings. Peter picks up, and Rick starts talking to him. Peter interrupts Rick by saying the following:
1. Look, I can't talk right now. I'm with John. He's been pushed by Bob and has hit his head.
2. Look, I can't talk right now. I'm with John. Bob has pushed him, and he's hit his head.
Are the bolded tenses used correctly? If so, does the passive voice "has been pushed" sound better than the active voice "has pushed" in this context? Which version would you use naturally? Thank you.

I can't see any possible reason for using Perfect forms for the first clause in either case. here. He was pushed by Bob and has hit his head is just about defensible (but has is at least unnecessary, if not actually undesirable). And Bob pushed him, and he hit his head is all you need. Avoid Perfect verb forms unless you know you need them.

Neither version. "I can't talk now. John hit his head when Bob pushed him."   Coordinating two independent clauses with and isn't as efficient as stating the main concern in the opening matrix clause and the context in the subordinate clause.

The second might mean that John hit Bob's head (perhaps with a fist).

In an emergency situation, why should Peter bother to go into detail about the incident, instead of just saying "John's hit his head on a door"? (Unless Bob has a reputation for violence and did it deliberately.)

OP's two sentences in active voice and passive voice

1. Look, I can't talk right now. I'm with John. He's been pushed by Bob and has hit his head..
2. Look, I can't talk right now. I'm with John. Bob has pushed him, and he's hit his head.

If there is no other choice the passive voice (sentence 1) is better because sentence 2 may be misinterpreted as , "Bob first pushed John and then Bob hit John on the head.".
The passive voice also lacks clarity.
There are better ways to explain this situation in Simple Past Tense.

John was hurt when Bob pushed him.
Bob pushed John and he accidentally hit his head.
Bob pushed John, causing him to hit his head.

These sentences can be rewritten in passive voice, without changing the meaning. For example:
4. John was hurt when he was pushed by Bob.

Side note: "he's hit" is short for "he has hit". It's still passive. But to the point ...
Active voice is used to say that some person or thing did something. Passive voice is used to say that something was done to him.
So, "Bob pushed John". Bob performed the action. In this case, he performed the action on John.
"John was pushed." John was the one who was pushed. The sentence does not specify who did the pushing.
Active voice is more common because it is more clear and direct. We use passive voice when we want to emphasize who received the action over who did it, or when we don't know who did it, or when we don't want to say who did it.
Like if I just found John lying on the floor hurt and I didn't know who pushed him, I might say, "John was pushed." I don't know by whom.
Or if I'm trying to describe what happened and I don't want to blame Bob, I might use passive voice. Maybe I'm afraid Bob will beat me up to, or it was an accident and I don't want to blame anyone.
There's a classic statement American politicians make, when they're caught in some wrongdoing, they don't say, "Yes, I accepted a bribe." They say, "Mistakes were made."

"He has hit his head" is not grammatically passive, even though John didn't do it to himself on purpose.

@KateBunting You're right. Brain freeze on my part.
